# How to show an overlay popup on tapping a button present inside listview item in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show an overlay popup when the button inside the list view item is tapped. And the overlay should be exactly below the button as shown in the image. How can I achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using tooltip, To customize your tooltip you can take a look [here](https://github.com/snj07/flutter_show_more_text_popup/blob/master/lib/show_more_text_popup.dart). Or it's example [here](https://github.com/snj07/flutter_show_more_text_popup/tree/master/example).